# angular $setviewvalue $parser conflict

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to implement an input tag that everytime I input a value, It add 1 automaticly.

Here is my code

```
    ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
      value = value + 1;

      if (ctrl.$viewValue !== value) {
        ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
        ctrl.$render();
      }
      console.info(value, ctrl.$viewValue);
      return value;
    });
```

But the result isn't what i want. I want it to update both the view and model, and just add 1.

I want to use $parsers to implement it, because the real world project need this... It's much more complex than this.

Here is plunker
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CROTfBfTKDjF6dR3EOoe?p=preview)

Comment: How is the condition `value.length < 11` related to your question

Comment: @PSL to stop infinite loop... I deleted it

Answer (score -3):

Just have a look at this simple code which I tried, may be useful for you

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div id="home" data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="add"  id="txt1" onchange="updateAngularModel(this.value)">{{add}}
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
</script>
<script>
 function updateAngularModel(val) {
 console.log("val==", val)
 document.getElementById("txt1").value++;
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but isn't it a hack?

Comment: i don't really understand..why to use such type of hack?

Comment: just because its not angular way.